# Feathers sequelize find by associated column

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, associations, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

I am trying to filter data based upon the value of an associated table, it works fine when i do a find all but when i try to search by name i get a column does not exist error

i have set up a hook like explained in https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-sequelize#associations

In postman i can see the association as a subkey but i cannot search by any columns

fetching code

```
service.find({
        query: {
          include: ["policyholders"],
          Name: {
            $like: `%somename%`,
          },
        },
      });
```

policies model

```
// See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/
// for more of what you can do here.
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;

module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get("sequelizeClient");
  const policies = sequelizeClient.define(
    "policies",
    {
      PolicyId: {
        autoIncrement: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      PolicyNumber: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
        allowNull: true,
      },
      PolicyHolderId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true
      },
    },
    {
      hooks: {
        beforeCount(options) {
          options.raw = true;
        },
      },
    }
  );

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  policies.associate = function (models) {
    // Define associations here
    // See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/
    const { policyholders } = models;
    policies.belongsTo(policyholders, { foreignKey: "PolicyholderId" });
  };

  return policies;
};
```

policyholders model

```
// See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/
// for more of what you can do here.
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;

module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get('sequelizeClient');
  const policyholders = sequelizeClient.define(
    'policyholders',
    {
      PolicyholderId: {
        autoIncrement: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      Name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(250),
        allowNull: true,
      },
    },
    {
      hooks: {
        beforeCount(options) {
          options.raw = true;
        },
      },
    }
  );

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  policyholders.associate = function (models) {
    // Define associations here
    // See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/
    const { policies } = models;

    policyholders.hasMany(policies, { foreignKey: { name: 'PolicyholderId' } });
  };

  return policyholders;
};
```

policies hook

```
const { authenticate } = require('@feathersjs/authentication').hooks;

const getRelated = require('../../hooks/get-related');

module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [ authenticate('jwt') ],
    find: [getRelated()],
    get: [getRelated()],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

  after: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

  error: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  }
};
```

hooks get related

```
module.exports = function (options = {}) {
  return async (context) => {
    const { include, ...query } = context.params.query;

    if (include) {


      const AssociatedModel = context.app.services.policyholders.Model;
      context.params.sequelize = {
        include: [{ model: AssociatedModel }],
        raw: false
      };

      
      // Update the query to not include `include`
      context.params.query = query;
    }

    return context;
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is too

```
 "$policyholder.Name%": {
            $like: `%somename%`,
          },
```

Then in the feathers service add the string to whitelist array